# Dynamic binding of private methods: Java vs. C++

Tags: java, c++, private, dynamic-binding

This is not allowed in Java:

```
class A { 
    public void method() {}
}

class B extends A { 
    private void method() {}
}
```

It generates a compile error:

```
error: method() in B cannot override method() in A 
attempting to assign weaker access privileges; was public
```

However, this IS allowed in C++:

```
class A { 
    public:
        virtual void method() {}
};

class B : public A { 
    private:
        void method() {}
};

int main(void) {
    A* obj = new B();
    obj->method(); // B::method is invoked, despite it being private
}
```

What's the logic behind this behavior in C++?

Comment: Java optimizes for the 90% use case. C++ optimizes for the 10%.

Comment: Java is more hand-holding. It constrains you more than C++ in the hope that most "sane" programs fit the constrains, and thus gives you less room to make mistakes.

Comment: С++ and Java are different languages for different purposes.

Comment: Actualy, `A::method()` _is_ being invoked. Being virtual, it gets polymorphic behaviour as designed.

Comment: @sehe I understand what you mean, but it's kind of hard to argue that `A::method` is being invoked when, if you place a print in each of `A::method` and `B::method`, only the latter print gets executed.

Comment: @sehe unlike user4815162342 I do not understand what you mean..

Comment: @Robz He means that, `obj` being of type `A*`, it is in a sense `A::method` that is being invoked. It being virtual, it dispatches to `B::method`, but that's not in any way visible to the compiler (the `A *obj` could point to an instance of any other `A` subclass).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Remember that the visibility of `method` is resolved purely at compile-time, C++ has no concept of a runtime verifier. What the compiler sees is a virtual `A::method`, which is *not* private. The concrete implementation *is* declared private, but that is only relevant when this implementation is directly invoked in a manner visible to the compiler, i.e. if you try to access it directly by calling it through `B`.

The logic of it is illustrated by the following case: Imagine if `B` didn't inherit from `A` publically, but privately — this is allowed in C++, and used when inheritance itself is an implementation detail, such as for a `stack` class inheriting from `vector`, but not wanting to expose the vector interface. In that case it would be a feature for `B::method` to be inaccessible, but `A::method` working just fine, even if the object is a `B` instance.

As Kerrek SB said, here Java is protecting you from one class of mistakes, at the cost of removing legitimate options.

Comment: So to be clear, in your example where class `B` privately inherits from class `A`: you're describing a situation where `B` might find it necessary to override some public `method` of `A`, but also might not want to expose `method` publicly?

Comment: @Robz Exactly. The virtual method will be called only when the object is accessed through its base (and from other methods, if they are calling it in their implementation).

Answer (score 2):

As for the virtual private methods part, this allows one to implement the [NVI pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-virtual_interface_pattern), so that you can do invariant checks or set-up/tear-down in a situation where inheritance is used.

Here is an example with a lock and a postcondition verification:

```
class base {
public:
    virtual ~base() = default;

    // Calls the derived class' implementation in a thread-safe manner.
    // @return A value greater than 42.
    int function() {
        std::lock_guard<std::mutex> guard(mutex);
        auto result = function_impl();
        assert(result > 42);
        return result;
    }

private:
    std::mutex mutex;
    virtual int function_impl() = 0; 
};

class derived : public base {
private:
    virtual int function_impl() override {
        return 0; // Whoops! A bug!
    }
};
```

In Java this could be achieved with protected methods, but that would leak implementation details to derived classes of derived classes which might be undesired.

As for the privatising otherwise public members part, if somebody would suddenly make `function_impl` public in `base`, it won’t break the derived classes. I’m not saying it’s a very good idea to do this, but C++ usually just assumes you know what you’re doing, hence it’s such a flexible language.

Comment: so the difference is that in C++ derived class can override private method whereas Java disallow it?

Comment: @BryanChen That was quite the point of the question if I understood it correctly.

Comment: I don't see how that is related to actually *hiding* a public member function in a derived type. Your original `::base::function_impl` was already private to begin with. The question asks why an originally *public* member function would be legal to be made private in a derived type.

Comment: I'd note that it would be risky to execute "arbitrary" derived-class code under a lock, unless the documentation made it very clear that the lock is being held. Unless you like deadlocks or badly performing code :0

Comment: @bitmask Oops, didn’t notice that part. Let me edit.

Comment: The point of hiding virtual methods is the same as the point of hiding any other methods - you want to deny access to a part of the inherited interface. This kind of thing is often done in C++, particularly to disable autogenerated copy constructors or assignment operators. Allowing it for a virtual method appears to makes no sense, but only if one conflates inheritance with interface inheritance. It's quite logical for *implementation inheritance*, where you inherit, but want to expose non of the inherited API. C++ supports doing this wholesale with the `private` inheritance keyword.